# hosting a html page with bokeh server

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am using bokeh server to publish my graph publicly. I am using multiple bokeh apps embedded within single bokeh server and using a following command to start bokeh server

```
        bokeh serve bokeh_app1 bokeh_app2 bokeh_app3
```

This works perfectly for me however I want to host another html page via bokeh server. Can we host html page using bokeh server just like we host html page using apache server? If yes, then how can we do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can, but I don't know if you should.

Here is at least one way to do it:

You can make a "dummy" bokeh app with a "regular" webpage as index.html in your app templates, and then add it to your bokeh serve command.

Empty `myapp/main.py`

And use any page you want as `myapp/templates/index.html`

Comment: Nice Idea. Thanks :)

Comment: I have multiple html pages Is there any in such  a way that they can be hosted by a single bokeh server?

Comment: @AvinashMagar I don't know if that is possible

Answer (score 1):

Found another way by setting up a new apache server which will be hosting multiple 
html pages.